# Ошибка при изменении product name и development target

Tags: ipad, xcode, ios, iphone, apple

Есть imageview. Product name - BlaBla и development target 6.0.
Если изменяю Product name - TestTest и development target 7.0, тогда в imageview не подтягивается картинка. 
Потом меняю обратно development target с 7.0 на 6.0 и изображение грузится в imageview.

Никак не пойму, в чем дело. Images.xcassets в проекте, и сами картинки есть. Как это вообще может быть связано?

Comment: Если используете Xcode 6, то в нем проблемма, как решать, я еще не разбирался. Но можно выложить все файлы из Images.xcassets в обычную папку и по старинке работать. Я удалил пока xcode6, и все ок. Но это если вам swift не нужен.

Comment: @Bimawa, так в том то и дело, что xcode 5. Вообще впервые столкнулся с данной проблемой.

Comment: Попробуйте почистить проект, может, бандлы не перебилдиваются.

Comment: Так это на постоянной основе - чистка не спасает.  Меняю Product name и ставлю development target 7 - нет картинок, меняю development target на 6 - есть картинки, меняю development target снова на 7 - уже тоже есть картинки. Меняю Product name и запускаю с тем же development target 7 - нет картинок... 

Ума не приложу, что делать - так и в аппстор попало без картинок, срочно фикс нужен...

Comment: У меня не работают cxassets в xCode6-Beta 1-5, в Beta6 все ок.

Comment: @iFreeman, разговор о работающем xcode 5.

Comment: Поменяйте таргет на 7, удалите кассеты и скопируйте с него, только с нуля создайте. Возьмите все картинки, сохраните где-нибудь, удалите все начисто, через файл создать касеты и туда скопировать на место. Помогло ли?

Comment: @Bimawa, нет - все тоже самое...

Comment: Неее, у меня кончились идеи... Надо проект смотреть.